# Screen title not centered

Tags: react-native

This is my HomeScreen.js:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import HomeScreenStyle from '../styles/ScreenStyles';
import { View, TouchableOpacity, Text, Image, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';


const HomeScreen =  ({ navigation }) => {
  return (
    <View style={HomeScreenStyle.container}>
        <Image source = {require("../assets/AppLogo.jpg")}/>
      </View>
  );
};


export default HomeScreen;
```

This is my HomeScreenStyle.js

```
import { StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

const HomeScreenStyle = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
      flex: 1,
      alignItems: 'center',
      justifyContent: 'center',
     },
       
  });

  export default HomeScreenStyle;
```

And this is my navigator which configures the title:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/native-stack';
import HomeScreen from '../screens/HomeScreen'

const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();

const MyStack = () => {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen
          name="Home"
          component={HomeScreen}
          options={{ title: 'Home' }}
        />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
};

export default MyStack;
```

[image]

As you can see in the photo the screen title is not centered, how can I achieve that?
thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just add `headerTitleAlign:'center'` to screen options :

```
<Stack.Screen
          name="Home"
          component={HomeScreen}
          options={{ title: 'Home',headerTitleAlign:'center' }}
        />
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the following **headerTitleAlign: 'center'** in the options so the stack screen will be

```
 <Stack.Screen
      name="Home"
      component={HomeScreen}
      options={{ title: 'Home',headerTitleAlign: 'center' }}
    />
```